# Filter a polars dataframe by date in rust

Tags: date, datetime, rust, time-series, rust-polars

Im trying to filter a dataframe by date.
But filter it with expressions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025510/filter-by-time-range-in-polars-rust) would be really cumbersome for a date like "2019-11-01 10:15:00".

My goal is to do something like the [python version](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/timeseries/selecting_dates.html):

```
use polars::export::chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use polars::prelude::*;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let df = LazyCsvReader::new(path)
        .with_parse_dates(true)
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?
        .collect()?;

    let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2019-11-01 10:15:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?;

    //This will not compile!
    let filtered = df.filter(col("time") < dt); 
}
```

However I'm having a really hard time to filter the dateframe in-place or just creating a boolean mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more time than I dare to admit I finally solved it by using the eager API, there is probably a better solution in the Lazy-API but this works for now!

```
use polars::export::chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use polars::prelude::*;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let df = LazyCsvReader::new(path)
        .with_parse_dates(true)
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?
        .collect()?;

// Set date to filter by
    let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2019-11-01 10:15:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?;

// Create boolean mask
    let mask = df["time"]
        .datetime()?
        .as_datetime_iter()
        .map(|x| x.unwrap() < dt)
        .collect();

// New filtered df
    let filtered_df = df.filter(&mask)?;
}
```

To get a date value from the "time" column and parse it to as a NaiveDateTime:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    // Lets take the last date from a series of datetime[µs]
    let date: Vec<Option<NaiveDateTime>> = df["time"]
        .tail(Some(1))
        .datetime()?
        .as_datetime_iter()
        .collect();

    // Create new NaiveDateTime, can be used as filter/condition in map-function
    let dt2 = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&date[0].unwrap().to_string(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?;
}
```