# Rust polars: Filter a lazy frame by datetime range

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am trying to filter a `LazyFrame` using a `chrono::NaiveDateTime` range.
Here is where I currently am at:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_lazy::prelude::*;

pub fn keep_range_lazy(
    df: &mut DataFrame,
    start: &NaiveDateTime,
    end: &NaiveDateTime,
) -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    assert!(
        df.get_column_names().contains(&"timestamp"),
        "Dataframe does not contain timestamp column."
    );

    df = &mut df
        .lazy()
        .filter(
            col("timestamp")
                .dt()
                .datetime()
                .gt_eq(start)
                .and(col("timestamp").dt().datetime().lt(end)),
        )
        .collect()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The above code fails because the `start` and `end` variables are not convertible to `Expr` types:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `polars_lazy::dsl::Expr: std::convert::From<&chrono::NaiveDateTime>` is not satisfied
   --> src/utils.rs:32:24
    |
32  |                 .gt_eq(start)
    |                  ----- ^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&chrono::NaiveDateTime>` is not implemented for `polars_lazy::dsl::Expr`
    |                  |
    |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`:
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<&str>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<bool>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<f32>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<f64>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<i32>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<i64>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<polars_lazy::dsl::AggExpr>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<u32>>
              <polars_lazy::dsl::Expr as std::convert::From<u64>>
    = note: required for `&chrono::NaiveDateTime` to implement `std::convert::Into<polars_lazy::dsl::Expr>`
note: required by a bound in `polars_plan::dsl::<impl polars_lazy::dsl::Expr>::gt_eq`
   --> /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/polars-plan-0.28.0/src/dsl/mod.rs:258:21
    |
258 |     pub fn gt_eq<E: Into<Expr>>(self, other: E) -> Expr {
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `polars_plan::dsl::<impl Expr>::gt_eq`
```

Notes:

- I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033885) which does not suit me because it implies using `.hours().minutes().seconds()` whilst there should be a way to simply use a single `DateTime` variable.
- I have [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75074358) which does not suit me either because it uses a `DataFrame` instead of a `LazyFrame`.
- The solution does not especially have to be inline. Meaning the final signature of that function could very well be `pub fn get_range_lazy(df: DataFrame, start: &NaiveDateTime, end: &NaiveDateTime) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>` if it does not imply a performance loss.

Here is the doc of [the polars DSL](https://docs.rs/polars-lazy/0.28.0/polars_lazy/dsl/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love the compiler errors in rust, they are so instructive as to the problem, and often even point to a solution! Like in this case, where they are telling you clearly that the trait bound is not satisfied but there are numerous implementations from integer types. To use the `NaiveDatetime` type we need only to cast the values to an appropriate integer value first. For example:

```rust
df.filter(
    col("timestamp")
        .gt_eq(start.timestamp_millis())
        .and(
            col("timestamp").lt(end.timestamp_millis()),
        ),
)
```

where I have used `timestamp_millis()` here as `"timestamp"` is in `ms`--your case may vary, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it indeed works, but I don't understand how it knows how to compare a `NaiveDateTime` with an `i64` in your code and not in the following code:  

`let d1 = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("01/01/2022 21:16:00.00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%.3f").unwrap();`  
`let d2 = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("12/30/2022 21:16:00.00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%.3f").unwrap();`  
`date < d1.timestamp_micros()`  

Could you please explain what is the difference with your example above ?

Comment: Comparison operators like `<` are not an `Expr`, you need to use something like `col("foo").lt(lit(date))`, or whatever, keeping in mind that under-the-hood `DataType::Datetime` is an integer.  See https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html